# Adding Mask Entry in Protobuf, and multiplying the same with gradient

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe, backpropagation, conv-neural-network

I have been working on pruning the neural network by discarding update to weight matrix by shielding weights below certain threshold.
To achieve this I have to add a field "mask" in [protobuf file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto), and later multiply (dot product) the same mask with diff (gradient) during back propagation by modifying the [`blob::update()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/blob.cpp).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this will be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to reference the paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02626v3.pdf

Comment: Thanks Shai, a little more help will be deeply appreciated :-)